# Discord.js 12 How to make bot leave when there are no people in the Voice Channel?

Tags: discord.js

I want to implement a check to see if there are no members in the voice channel the bot is in, so it can automatically disconnect and not stay there till I disconnect it or someone else does.

I had been searching around for any example, but found no relevant answers to my questions.

Anyone that can help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using the `voiceStateUpdate` event. In the event, check if there are members in the voicechannel. If not, then make the bot leave.

[VoiceStateUpdate - Docs](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-voiceStateUpdate)

[Check if user is in an specific voice Channel - Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65961002/discord-js-check-if-user-is-in-an-specific-voice-channel)

Comment: Thank you! Much appreciated.

Comment: @nikoszz Your welcome! If this answers your question, please accept it, so both of us gain more reputation and other users can see that this answer solved your problem. See this link: [stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers](https://www.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) :D